# Moving from a self and init workspace to a more simplified workspace

Tags: python, matplotlib, methods

How do I shy away from using self, init, try and except. To give some background, this is code for a live biosensor stream. However, I am struggling to dumb the code down. The code constantly updates and then the code is plotted in matplotlib.

I want to get rid of all these methods because the logic and code is hard to work with.

MAIN QUESTION: What is the process of this code? What si the order fo the functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I personally recommend classes as they will make it very easy to store data and transfer it from one function to another, it is cetainly possible to re-write the code outside of a class. You would need to remove the contents of the`__init__` function and move them to the main indentation level, remove "self." from wherever you see it, and input the necessary variables to each function instead of self, i.e. `update_vars(self)` would become `def updateVars(board, display_window, board_channel)`

Instead of doing this though, I recommend trying to learn how classes work. To start, when a class is initialized, in this case with `stream = CytonStream()` the `__init__` function is called to initialize an instance of the CythonStream object. Inside of the CytonStream methods, `self` refers to this instance of the class. `self` references inside the class are functionally the same as `stream` references outside of the class because if you were to call `stream.updateVars()`, `stream` will get passed into `updateVars` in the same way as if you called `CytonStream.updateVars(stream)`.

Inside `__init__` you will notice that attributes are assigned to the class instance `self`:

```
self.display_window = DataFilter.get_nearest_power_of_two(500)
```

This variable now is accessible anywhere that you can access `self` or `stream`. So in `updateVars` you can access this attribute.

```
all_data = self.board.get_current_board_data(self.display_window)
```

And if you were to do `stream.display_window` it would give you this same attribute.

As far as what is happening in your code, when you run `stream = CytonStream()`, this calls `CytonStream.__init__()`. Inside this function,

```
self.ani = matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.updateFig,
                                                      interval=5, blit=True)
```

an animation is created which will call `self.updateFig()`, which will call `self.updateVars()`

Comment: You are seriously soo awesome!! Really appreciate this thorough explanation. Would upvote this but don't have enough reputation :)